# Htaccess и ссылки вида /page/name?param=test

Tags: .htaccess, регулярные-выражения, ссылки, чпу

Добрый день, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с htaccess. 
Хочется получить ссылки ввида:

```
/page/name?param=test
```

где page - название страницы;
name - название первого параметра (пусть будет тоже name);
param - второй параметр, test - его значение (для примера, может меняться).

Так вот, каким образом можно заставить htaccess приводить ссылки к такому виду?
Сейчас у меня работает вот такое для одного параметра, а нужно добавить ещё:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ index.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

По всякому пытался менять, но безуспешно. Первый параметр забирает в себя своё значение и значение второго параметра:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)(\?(.*))?$ index.php?name=$1&param=$2 [NC,L]
```

Я понимаю, что всё из-за `(.*)`, но как сказать, что мне нужно считывать первый параметр до `?`, не знаю.

Comment: А разве `^(.*)/(.*)` не достаточно ? Либо просто не задавать второй параметр, и он будет просто как `?param=test`.

Comment: Ах да, забыл указать, что первый параметр присутствует обязательно, а вот второй нет. 

То есть ссылка вида
/page/name должна нормально отработать, разобрав в первый параметр name, ну и соответственно /page/name?param=test должна разбирать 2 параметра.

Comment: @Bastian, в вашем случае будет вот так:  

page/author/20/something/more синоним для index.php?name=author&param=/20/something/more

Все из-за того, что вы не фильтруете слэш.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ /index.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?name=$1&param=$2 [NC,L]
```

Учтите, что это действительно только для вариантов без слэша на конце.
Примеры:

```
page/                             не попадает под правило
page/author                       синоним для index.php?name=author
page/author/                      не попадает под правило
page/author/20                    синоним для index.php?name=author&param=20
page/author/20/                   не попадает под правило
page/author/20/something          не попадает под правило
```

Чтобы учитывались с конечным слэшем и без него, нужно написать так:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?name=$1&param=$2 [NC,L]
```

Тогда правила будут срабатывать так:

```
page/                             не попадает под правило
page/author                       синоним для index.php?name=author
page/author/                      синоним для index.php?name=author
page/author/20                    синоним для index.php?name=author&param=20
page/author/20/                   синоним для index.php?name=author&param=20
page/author/20/something          не попадает под правило
```

**Обновление:**

```
# Строка вида profile/test без QUERY_STRING
# Вместо test может быть любое значение
# В качестве примера, для этого случая подставлено значение page=1 в целевой URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)$ /profile.php?name=$1&page=1 [NC,L]

# Строка вида profile/test?page=8
# Вместо test может быть любое значение
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)$ /profile.php?name=$1&page=%1 [NC,L]
```

Разберем построчно:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
```

`RewriteCond` - это "условие" для срабатывания первого нижеследующего "правила" `RewriteRule`. Перед правилом может быть несколько условий. Проверяться они будут последовательно.

`%{QUERY_STRING}` - это все, что идет после знака вопроса.
для `profile/test?page=8` `%{QUERY_STRING}` будет таким: `page=8`
`^$` - означает пустую строку.
Все вместе это означает, что в URL нет запроса с параметрами, т.е. страница такого вида `profile/test`.

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)$ /profile.php?name=$1&page=1 [NC,L]
```

`RewriteRule` - как и говорил выше, это правило редиректа.

`^profile/([^/]+)$` означает любую страницу, первая часть адреса которой начинается с profile/ а далее следует любой символ (как минимум 1), кроме "/". Значение в скобках будет запомнено. Иными словами profile/test глазами машины: profile/(test). Условию удовлетворяет, "test" сохранено в переменную. Имена переменным даются автоматически. Это числительные, начиная с 1. Сколько парных скобок - столько переменных.

В случае с правилом редиректа, указатель на переменную - это знак "$". Т.е. переменная, содержащая "test" будет вида $1 (1 - потому что это первая пара скобок).

`/profile.php?name=$1&page=1` для нашего примера равно `/profile.php?name=test&page=1`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(\d+)$
```

`^page=(\d+)$` - ищем url, с такими параметрами запроса:

```
?page=число_которое_будет_сохранено_в_переменную_потому_что_выражение_в_скобках
```

Для `?page=8` в переменную будет сохранено число "8".

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)$ /profile.php?name=$1&page=%1 [NC,L]
```

В случае с условием редиректа, указатель на переменную - это знак "%". Т.е. переменная, содержащая "8" будет вида %1 (1 - потому что это первая пара скобок).

`/profile.php?name=$1&page=%1` для нашего примера равно `/profile.php?name=test&page=8`

Почему? Потому что `$1 = "test"`, а `%1 = "8"`

Приоритеты нумерации скобок: снаружи вовнутрь, слева направо.

Comment: Мне не нравятся ссылки в таком формате, и как сделать такое, я знаю. Я же указал в первом сообщении, что хочу получить первый параметр в формате
page/author, а второй параметр уже потом добавляя ? в конец (ну по стандарту, как без ЧПУ если). И второй параметр необязателен, а слеш после author мне не нужен.

Вот реальный пример:

    /profile/test?page=8
 
То есть отображение профиля пользователя test и списка его новостей на 8 странице. `/profile/test/page/8` - знаю, как сделать такое, это не подходит.

Comment: @Floyat, вы меня запутали. Пожалуйста, укажите полную ссылку как есть сейчас и полную ссылку как вы хотите, чтобы было. Сделайте больше полных примеров. И так для каждого варианта. Тогда я исправлю ответ.

Comment: Стандартная ссылка:
profile.php?name=test&page=8 
Хочу:
profile/test?page=8 
При этом чтобы 
profile/test 
нормально работало без второго параметра(с номерами страниц я сам разберусь, просто чтобы не было 403 ошибки, если не передан второй параметр)

Comment: @Floyat, обновил свой ответ. Надеюсь, теперь я вас правильно понял.

Comment: Спасибо, это работает. Я не совсем понял, как и почему. Но буду разбираться в книжке.

Comment: @Floyat, я постарался объяснить, что откуда получилось.